# Hibernate Oracle Create table

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jdbc

I have a problem while creating table in oracle via hibernate.
I get these two error:

```
Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

and

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

This is my **hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">system</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">mypass</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">SamTest</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">5</property>
                <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <mapping class="com.sam.Teacher" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Teacher** entity

```
@Table(schema="SamTest")
public class Teacher {

    @Id
    //@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
    private int teacher_Id;
    @Column
    private int teacher_No;
    @Column
    private String teacher_Name;
    @Column
    private String teacher_Surname;
    @Column
    private String department;


    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public int getTeacher_Id() {
        return teacher_Id;
    }

    public void setTeacher_Id(int teacher_Id) {
        this.teacher_Id = teacher_Id;
    }

    public int getTeacher_No() {
        return teacher_No;
    }

    public void setTeacher_No(int teacher_No) {
        this.teacher_No = teacher_No;
    }

    public String getTeacher_Name() {
        return teacher_Name;
    }

    public void setTeacher_Name(String teacher_Name) {
        this.teacher_Name = teacher_Name;
    }

    public String getTeacher_Surname() {
        return teacher_Surname;
    }

    public void setTeacher_Surname(String teacher_Surname) {
        this.teacher_Surname = teacher_Surname;
    }

    public Teacher() {
    }

    public Teacher(int teacher_No, String teacher_Name, String teacher_Surname, String department) {
        this.teacher_No = teacher_No;
        this.teacher_Name = teacher_Name;
        this.teacher_Surname = teacher_Surname;
        this.department=department;
    }

}
```

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at com.sam.RunHiber.main(RunHiber.java:23)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10500)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Can you post the entire exception?

Comment: Any SQL in the log? Which query failed?

Comment: SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
    .buildSessionFactory();

  Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
  Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

  Teacher teacher = new Teacher(444, "sds", "sdfd", "dfg");

  session.save(teacher);

  tx.commit();
  session.flush();
  session.close();
  System.out.println("Calisti");

Comment: It is unlikely that your schema is called `SamTest`. It is more likely to be `SAMTEST`. When in doubt what Hibernate does, turn on SQL statement logging, e.g. in log4j.properties add `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're creating getters and setters in Hibernate, but I'm pretty sure you're not creating a table. This is only the reference to an Oracle table that obviously does not exist (yet). Hence the error "Table or view does not exists".